# Understanding QML Slider

Tags: slider, qml, qt5.6

I am doing a simple slider project just to understand how sliders work in QML.
I am using the slider from `Qt.labs.controls`
I looked at their documentation and there are only two methods.

`void decrease()` and `void increase()`

All I want to do is display the value corresponding to the slider position.
I can't find any signal or method that tells me if the current position changed or something like that.
Am I looking in the right place?
Or Do I have to write everything from scratch to make my simple project work?

Update: I am using QT5.6 should I use higher version for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specifically mentioned labs, which means you're probably using QtQuick 2. There's been a lot of important developments of the Controls components since Qt5.6, so it would be advisable to upgrade if the intention is to continue using QtQuick 2.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-slider.html gives the latest docs. Note that the widget was updated in Qt5.7, and that the current import command is `import QtQuick.Controls 2.1`.

The latest Qt is 5.8, in which the Slider supports both `position`, and `value`.

- `position`: the slider's position, from 0 to 1.
- `value`: the output value mapped from `position` onto the scale [`from`, `to`]

Answer (score 0):

You can use value property of that control. Every qml property has implicit signal handler.For ex: for value property you will have signal onValueChanged.
For your simple project you can also use slider control from QtQuick.Controls. Just import QtQuick.Controls 1.4 in your qml file.